# Текст в поле Input не появляется

Tags: javascript, html, css

Пишу калькулятор и столкнулась с проблемой, что текст не выводится при работе скрипта в поле с id summa2.

```css
input[type="text"] {
  width: 40px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="rus">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <title>BANK</title>

  <script>
    function fun1() {
      var rng = document.getElementById('begunok');
      var summa2 = document.getElementById('summa2');
      summa2.innerHTML = rng.value;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <input id="begunok" type="range" oninput="fun1()">
  <input id="summa2" type="text">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Поле просто пустое при движении ползунка.

Comment: Вместо `summa2.innerHTML = rng.value;` нужно использовать `summa2.value = rng.value;`

Comment: Тег `Input` является одиночным и не должен содержать внутри себя `html`, вы можете лишь передать в него значение, а вывести html можно в любой другой **парный тег**, к примеру в тот же `<p id="text"></p>`

Comment: Опишите поточней что вы хотите чтобы происходило когда вы перемещаете ползунок и вам помогут, т.к. сейчас мой комментарий и является ответом на ваш вопрос но вам нужно что-то другое, а что, никто не понял!!!

Comment: спасибо. поняла

Comment: Вы также могли вставить тело вопроса в визуальный редактор _(посмотрите как он выглядит сейчас)_, в котором есть автовыравнивание кода и который позволит воспроизвести его выполнение, такое размещение я думаю привлечет больше внимание и проявит желание помочь, просьба впредь оформлять вопрос более грамотно.